# Setting Series.Formula property with VBA in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I have a single chart in an Excel 2016 workbook. The macro below should replace each of the eight series formulas' source sheets with the last eight sheets of a separate workbook. Trying to run it crashes excel, and does not modify the chart.

```
Sub ChangeSourceData()
    Dim chartBook As Workbook
    Dim dataBook As Workbook
    Dim sheetNumber As Long
    Dim cementID As String
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim mySeries As Series
    Dim seriesNumber As Long

    Set chartBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set dataBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="S:\Current Projects\R&D\CalorimetryDataOPCAutomated.xlsx")
    sheetNumber = dataBook.Worksheets.Count
    seriesNumber = 1

    For Each myChart In chartBook.Charts
        For Each mySeries In myChart.SeriesCollection
            cementID = dataBook.Worksheets(sheetNumber).Name
            mySeries.Formula = "=SERIES('[CalorimetryDataOPCAutomated.xlsx]" & cementID & _
            "'!$B$2,'[CalorimetryDataOPCAutomated.xlsx]" & cementID & _
            "'!$B$4:$B$5000,'[CalorimetryDataOPCAutomated.xlsx]" & cementID & _
            "'!$F$4:$F$5000," & seriesNumber & ")"
            sheetNumber = sheetNumber - 1
            seriesNumber = seriesNumber + 1
        Next mySeries
    Next myChart
End Sub
```

I have run this macro with the `mySeries.Formula` string assigned to a `String` variable `test` which I can `Debug.Print` just fine. I have tried to `Set mySeries.Formula` but it doesn't appear that's the correct way to modify the formula. I've tried `mySeries.Formula = Replace(mySeries.Formula, mySeries.Formula, newFormula)` which also causes a crash.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: For starters, your `seriesNumber = 1` should be inside the `For each mychart` loop.

Comment: @Rory Sure thing, thanks. Though it shouldn't be a problem with only the one chart for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by modifying each of the individual components, rather than the complete formula. I replaced:

```
        cementID = dataBook.Worksheets(sheetNumber).Name
        mySeries.Formula = "=SERIES('[CalorimetryDataOPCAutomated.xlsx]" & cementID & _
        "'!$B$2,'[CalorimetryDataOPCAutomated.xlsx]" & cementID & _
        "'!$B$4:$B$5000,'[CalorimetryDataOPCAutomated.xlsx]" & cementID & _
        "'!$F$4:$F$5000," & seriesNumber & ")"
        seriesNumber = seriesNumber + 1
```

with:

```
    With mySeries
        .Name = dataBook.Worksheets(sheetNumber).Name
        .Values = dataBook.Worksheets(sheetNumber).Range("F4:F5000")
        .XValues = dataBook.Worksheets(sheetNumber).Range("B4:B5000")
    End With
```

which now works perfectly.